# Calling C# window service

Tags: window, driver

I'm writing a  Windows service in C# in Visual Studio  2015 Enterprise.
I want to add Windows Driver (Callout Driver) (C++), to the Windows service C#. Can someone kindly  give
  me a hint on how to add the Windows Driver (C++) to my windows service application?
Calling the Windows Driver (Callout Driver) from C# window service  `OnStart()`.